# No rows in result set when trying to deploy a business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I get the following error when trying to deploy a fabric composer business network archive to a 0.6 local hyperledger fabric setup.

```
BusinessNetworkDefinition:fromArchive()             < [object Object]
HFCConnection            :deploy()                  Deploying business network org.acme.biznet@0.0.1
FSConnectionProfileStore :load()                    Loaded connection profile hlfabric {
    "type": "hlf",
    "membershipServicesURL": "grpc://localhost:7054",
    "peerURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
    "eventHubURL": "grpc://localhost:7053",
    "keyValStore": "/tmp/keyValStore",
    "deployWaitTime": 300,
    "invokeWaitTime": 30,
    "certificate": null,
    "certificatePath": null
}
HFCUtil                  :deployChainCode()         function init force true concerto
HFCUtil                  :deployChainCode()         onError {"error":{"code":2,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}}},"msg":"Error: sql: no rows in result set"}
ConnectorServer          :Error: Error: sql: no rows in result set() undefined 
ConnectorServer          :connectionDeploy()        <
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enroll with a hyperledger fabric instance, the credentials are stored in the keyValStore directory defined in your connection profile. If you then try to interact with a different hyperledger fabric instance or your stop and restart the docker containers for a locally running hyperledger fabric instance (effectively defining a new instance) with the same connection profile and this the credentials already stored in the keyValStore you get this error. This is because the credentials are not valid for that instance. 
To fix the problem, either change your connection profile to use a different directory for keyValStore or remove that directory and it's contents and try again.